# Get Session start information if Session is turned off in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, session, global-asax

I have an ASP .NET information and I currently have session state turned off so I can't exactly hook into the session start event within the Global.asax. I want to get at this data, when someone comes to a site, and when they would normally start a session. What is the event that is fired to start a session so that I could hook into it and get at that data?

Answer (score 3):

Without having sessions turned on then **every** request is a new session. So whatever event you like :)

Unless you're dropping a cookie which acts as a session cookie then there is no way to know if a visitor has been there before.